# Is there a css image replacement technique that covers all the bases?

Tags: image, css

I have been scouring the web to try to find the "perfect" technique for this.  Is there something I have missed that solves CSS on/off,  unnecessary markup,  and does not need a hack with older IE (I know that is pushing it)?  I mainly want to replace a header logo.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique used in [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) is solid. Specifically:

http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/The-style/#ir

Comment: I like this.  I am tinkering with it.  Still trying to figure out why when I apply the text-indent and it takes the text and my image too.  I want it to just take the text and leave the link to the index page attached to my logo/image with out the text there.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know why text-indent would move the background of the elemtn. Perhaps you need to anchor the background image to the container using `background-position`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific class on the element that need to be replaced, you can use this method:

http://www.audenaerde.org/csstricks.html#imagereplacecss

Works in all the browsers since IE6.